# Draw to another application window with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

In my program, I have to run another application (which draws something with OpenGL), and draw in it.

How can I do this in Windows, or with Qt?

Article with solution, can be found [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/login.jsp?url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel5%2F4414509%2F4414510%2F04414576.pdf%3Farnumber%3D4414576&authDecision=-203).

Comment: Please be more specific and/or give us some example code. What do you mean with "In my programm I have to run another application"? Do you start a new process from your program?

Comment: There is no any code just for now. "Do you start a new process from your program?" Yes, I think so. I choose which program to run (exe file), get the image drawn by this program (by opengl), use it as a texture, make some transform and replase the original image.

Comment: @Jeka: could you elaborate a little bit more? You should also know that the solutions to do this (like the hooking already answered) can trigger things like anti-virus/anti-cheat programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> run another application (which draw smth with OpenGl), and draw in it.
>
> get the image drawn by this program (by opengl), use it as a texture, make some transform and replase the original image.

Those are two rather different things. The "easiest" and "cleanest" way (if you can call it that, at all) to do what you apparently want according to the further clarification would be to hook `wglSwapLayerBuffers` (which *seems to be* what `SwapBuffers`and `wglSwapBuffers` call internally, you'll need to confirm that or hook all three).

You then possess a valid context handle, and at the time buffers have been swapped, you are sure (necessarily!) that the framebuffer contents are valid and consistent, no half-drawn primitives exist. Therefore, nothing hinders you to read back the front or back buffer (or both!), run some kernel over it, and write it back before returning control to the application.

Since the context handle is only valid for the process, the only way that reliably works without trouble and without some *really nasty* hacks (more nasty than this is already) is by inserting a fake `opengl32.dll`, much like tools such as GLIntercept do.
You could probably "steal" the handle from a mini-debugger, too, but it won't be valid for your process, so no use.

But... like datenwolf said: just don't do it.

Comment: Ohh, look's really nasty. So programms like fraps (which indicates FPS over program) working in same way?

Comment: Most probably. The actual FPS _display_ is trivial, this can be done with a layered window, using nothing but GDI. But since _knowing_ the FPS involves knowing when (or how often) buffers were switched, they probably need to do API hooking anyway. The only alternative would be to read some IHV specific performance counter, but that's just as well trouble and less portable...

Comment: Can I, at least, get image to process in my app? Should I use hooks to keep this up to date?

Comment: Yes, as described above. Nothing hinders you to read the image data into a named shared memory object that another program can read and modify. It just isn't pretty, requires proper synchronisation (which can be tricky), and is an awful lot of work for something that is probably either not very useful or or done better with other means (display settings) or in another place (the original application). I just can't imagine what kind of "image processing" I'd reasonably like to have for "any unknown other program".

Comment: Under "Image processing", I mean some transformation for half cylinder display, like this: [link](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/login.jsp?url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel5%2F4414509%2F4414510%2F04414576.pdf%3Farnumber%3D4414576&authDecision=-203) [link](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/cylmapper/)

Comment: Quote from the first link you posted: _"For applications based on OpenGL, we make a new opengl32.dll to intercept the OpenGL API functions (especially SwapBuffer) in Windows operating system's library search path."_ That's basically word by word what I wrote :-)

Comment: Yes it is. I found it little bit later ;) Thanks you all!

Answer (score 0):

In Windows only using very obscure and dirty hacks. I don't recommend it. Qt is just a framework, which depends on the underlaying OS. On Windows all constraints of Windows apply.

On X11 you can create OpenGL contexts in two modes: *direct* or *indirect* (see the *direct* parameter of glXCreateContext and glXCreateNewContext). Indirect contexts can be shared between X clients, because to the X-server there are no processes or distinct clients. There are only XIDs, with the OpenGL context being one of them. That allows you to pass the XID of a indirect OpenGL context between processes connected to the same X display. Direct contexts bypass the GLX protocol, and thereby cannot be shared, though.

Comment: "In Windows only using very obscure and dirty hacks" I understand it, but I really need it. Qt is just framework in which another part of my project written, so I am going use it in this app.

Thanks for X11 explaning, but it not interesting for me.

Comment: @Jeka: I don't even know if the hack that once worked in Win2k still does. Effectively you're attaching your own program to the other program as if it were a debugger and call OS functions from the other program's context. This is really something not very reliable and easy to get to work. What would work is providing an RPC interface to the OpenGL functions.

Comment: I have tried generating an indirect context in the same Display and Visual that I have a direct context, and glXCreateContext consistently returns null any time I try to generate an indirect context. Any idea what's going on there?

Comment: @CharlesLohr: For a few years now the X.org server has indirect GLX disabled by default, but you can reenable it with the `IndirectGLX` server flags option in `xorg.conf`